# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.SQLExecutionTag

Tags: java, sql, jsp, jstl

This might be a noob question but i'm stuck in this error. I'm using Tomcat 7.0.34

```
WebContent/WEB-INF/lib
       jstl-1.2-sources.jar
       jstl-1-2.jar
       mysql-connector-java-5.1.31
```

below is my jsp code.

```
<sql:setDataSource var="con" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" user="root" password=""/>
    <sql:query var="result" sql="select * from account" dataSource="${con }"/>
    <c:forEach var="rows" items="${result.rows }">
        ${rows.email}
    </c:forEach>
```

full stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/JavaPMS] threw exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/sql/SQLExecutionTag] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.SQLExecutionTag
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1223)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1452)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

it seems to be working fine if I'll remove `<sql:query/>`.

Thank you.

Comment: have you included sql and core tag library?

Answer (score 2):

please download both this jar and try this hopefully is should work.

put them  in below location

WebContent/WEB-INF/lib

- [jsf-api.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jsp-api/2.0/jsp-api-2.0.jar)
- [jstl.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar)

Comment: no need for jsp-api.jar it's already included in the tomcat lib by default. and also what's the difference between jstl-1.2 and jstl-1.2.1? I notice it won't work if combine jstl-1.2.1.jar and jstl-1.2-source.jar.

Answer (score 0):

you have specified query attribute , but it should be like below,

```
<sql:setDataSource var="con" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" user="root" password=""/>
    <sql:query var="result" dataSource="${con }">
select * from account
</sql:query>
    <c:forEach var="rows" items="${result.rows }">
        ${rows.email}
    </c:forEach>
```

it should work as expected

Comment: same thing works for me .check whether you have imported essential tag libs

Comment: the exception suggests that `Execution` tag lib is missing . try remove the tag libs and add it again

Comment: java SqlExecutionTag class is included in jstl-1.2.jar. So what do u mean by Execution tag lib?

Comment: this url `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>` indicates support for sql tags . have you included this ?

Comment: your exception says the compiler cant find the class, that is required to execute the query in its class path

Comment: yes. both `<%@taglib prefix="c"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>` is included

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error, every time I run the app, I tired changing the mysql connector dependencies with several version but error was still their, I read my code many time and not found anything also tried cj and without cj in driver even then it doesn't work but then I re-load my Intellij IDEA Ultimate edition (IDE) and guess it's working :-<>